# Tooling API to get the ID of the field

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api

Does the Tooling API count against the Org limit?

I have a scenario in which I need to create custom button on related list and by pass record type selection page and re-direct to appropriate Page layout/record type automatically based on the values of the Parent record.

Since the re-direction is done through Visual Force, I need to automatically populate some of the Lookup fields on child record using Apex. To achieve this, I need the Id of the lookup fields on the child record.

The way I'm making it work right now:
1. Store the values of look up field in Custom setting.

The way I want it to work:
1. Extract the Id of look up field dynamically using Tooling API. Now I'm confused, if make a rest call to Tooling API, will it count against my Org limit?

Please advice.

Comment: You're asking about the number of calls to the Tooling API, right?

Comment: Yes it was tooling API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Tooling API counts as calls against your org. Usually, thus won't matter, unless you expect this function to be called very frequently. You might use a hybrid approach. Cache the response in custom settings, and use those values when available.

Comment: Yeah the hybrid approach sounds good.. That way it will just be 1 call and going forward Custom setting will be used.. thanks again!